Preview uploaded CSV file in Filament / Laravel / Livewire
I am trying to build a web app in Laravel / Filament, where users are able to import data from a CSV file. However, I want to build a 2 step form in my filament resource with the wizard.
I am building an ImportResource which will make users able to upload a csv file, add a name and then go to the next step, which is the CSV preview.
I have tried all sorts of things, building a Filament component, building a Livewire component, passing the data directly. But I really don't know how to do this...
What I have right now, my ImportResource:
namespace App\Filament\Resources;

use App\Filament\Resources\ImportResource\Pages;
use App\Models\Import;
use Filament\Forms;
use Filament\Resources\Resource;
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ImportResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Import::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-rectangle-stack';

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\Wizard::make([
                    Forms\Components\Wizard\Step::make('Import Details')
                        ->columnSpan('full')
                        ->columns('1')
                        ->description('Upload your csv file')
                        ->schema([
                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                                ->required()
                                ->label('Import Name'),
                            Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('file')
                                ->label('CSV File')
                                ->acceptedFileTypes(['text/csv', 'text/plain'])
                                ->directory('uploads/imports')
                                ->getUploadedFileNameForStorageUsing(function ($file): string {
                                    return now()->timestamp . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                                })
                                ->maxSize(51200)
                                ->required()
                                ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, $set, $get) {
                                  if ($state) {
                                      $tmpPath = $state->getRealPath();
  
                                      // Read CSV file and set preview data
                                      $csv = Reader::createFromPath($tmpPath, 'r');
                                      $csv->setHeaderOffset(0);
                                      $headers = $csv->getHeader(); // Get the header of the CSV file
                                      $records = $csv->getRecords(); // Get all records of the CSV file
                                      $rows = [];
                                      foreach ($records as $record) {
                                          $rows[] = $record;
                                          if (count($rows) >= 5) break; // Take the first 5 rows
                                      }
  
                                      $set('csv_preview_headers', $headers);
                                      $set('csv_preview_rows', $rows);
  
                                      // Prepare the final path
                                      $path = 'uploads/imports/' . now()->timestamp . '-' . $state->getClientOriginalName();
                                      $set('file_path', $path);
                                  }
                              }),
                        ]),
                    Forms\Components\Wizard\Step::make('CSV Preview')
                        ->description('Review your upload')
                        ->schema([
                            Forms\Components\View::make('components.import-preview')
                                ->extraAttributes([
                                  'headers' => fn ($get) => $get('csv_preview_headers'),
                                  'rows' => fn ($get) => $get('csv_preview_rows'),
                            ]),
                        ]),
                ])
            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('name')->label('Import Name'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('status')->label('Status'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('rows_processed')->label('Rows Processed'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('created_at')->dateTime()->label('Created At'),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\DeleteAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListImports::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateImport::route('/create'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditImport::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }
}

Now, I would think that this part:
$set('csv_preview_headers', $headers);
$set('csv_preview_rows', $rows);

Would make the csv_preview_headers available to pass to a livewire component and render this with Forms\Components\View::make('components.import-preview').
This is my import-preview.blade.php file:
@props(['headers' => [, 'rows' => []])

@if ($headers && $rows)
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach ($headers as $header)
                    <th>{{ $header }}</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($rows as $row)
                <tr>
                    @foreach ($row as $cell)
                        <td>{{ $cell }}</td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@else
    <p>No data to preview.</p>
@endif

But, the file upload works. And then I click the next button to go to the next step, and it keeps showing "No data to preview".
I have no idea how to fix this, been at this for hours.
Anyone that knows how I can use the data in my uploaded .csv (which does not exist on the server yet, because the file has not been saved) to preview it with a component in step 2 of the form?
Kind regards,
Syb.

why not save the file in a temporary folder? I'm not sure you can find the file again after finishing the first step, as that request has been closed.
